# Stark VS Thanos

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

Thanos has invaded the Avengers. In the final standoff, Iron Man is off to fight the Mad Titan. Iron Man has created anti-infinity Stones to finish Thanos. But, the anti-Infinity stones can only be used together using a password. Iron Man has created a password of 6 numbers, where each number represents an anti-Infinity Stone.

```
 Iron Man only remembers 5 and has forgotten the 6th. What should be the 6th number so that the billionaire genius can destroy Thanos?

  The first 5 numbers of the password are:

    1210 

    2020 

    21200

    3211000

    42101000
```

What should be the final number for the password?
(Iron Man needs to quickly remember the 6th number, before Thanos figures out the logic behind the password!!!)

Comment: ...but it was too late... and the final words heard from humankind escaped the mouth of the Herculean being by the name of Thanos: "I am inevitable." ***SNAP*** xD

Comment: I just hope that nobody hides an End Game spoiler in an answer's spoiler

Comment: Spoiler: rot13(uggcf://vzntrf-an.ffy-vzntrf-nznmba.pbz/vzntrf/V/614VCBh86dY._FL355_.wct)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Gareth's reasoning is correct. However,

> what he gave was the 7th number. There is another smaller number that fulfils the condition, and would thus be next in sequence: **521001000**

Comment: Ooops! I confess I assumed from the framing story that there were exactly six such numbers, so when I found another I assumed it was the next one. Good catch!

Answer (score 20):

The sixth number is

> 6210001000

and these are

> numbers that count their own digits. So, e.g., 1210 has **one** 0, **two** 1s, **one** 2, **zero** threes.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A138480](https://oeis.org/A138480)

Comment: Close call. You almost had it much like the Gauntlet from Thanos in Infinty War!!

Comment: D'oh: if I'd thought to check OEIS I wouldn't have missed the fact that there's another smaller one :-).